# JavaFX CheckBoxTreeItem detect when checkbox selected or unselected

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How do I detect when a `CheckBoxTreeItem` is selected or unselected?

Do I use an event handler or change listener or something? What event am I checking for? Is there a list of events that I can listen for like checkboxtreeitem.selection or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go to see the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBoxTreeItem.html

You'll see that there is a method called 'addEventHandler', I think it's what you're looking for.

```
public <E extends Event> void addEventHandler(EventType<E> eventType,
                                          EventHandler<E> eventHandler)
```

'Registers an event handler to this TreeItem. The TreeItem class allows registration of listeners which will be notified as the number of items changes, their position or if the values themselves change'

Comment: Why is it when I use the follow it activates twice i.e. displays aa when I only select on checkbox?

'    public void setTreeViewEventHandler(CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem) {
        checkBoxTreeItem.addEventHandler(CheckBoxTreeItem.<String>checkBoxSelectionChangedEvent(), new EventHandler<CheckBoxTreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<String>>() {
            public void handle(CheckBoxTreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<String> event) {
                System.out.print("a");
            }
        });
    }'

Comment: Try to print the event recorder: 'CheckBoxTreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<String> event' in the handle() method

Answer (score 5):

You can for example listen to the [`selectedProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBoxTreeItem.html#selectedProperty)   of `CheckBoxTreeItem` by adding a listener when you create the nodes of the tree:

```
CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Root");
rootItem.setExpanded(true);

final TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>(rootItem);
tree.setEditable(true);

tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String> forTreeView());

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Item" + (i + 1));

    checkBoxTreeItem.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        System.out.println(checkBoxTreeItem.getValue() + " selection state: " + newVal);
    });

    rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);
}
```

This tree prints for example:

```
Item8 selection state: true
Item8 selection state: false
```